# Drag Image facility

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event

I want to **move image in android on touch** event as my finger moves image must move with coordinates of finger. Please any one can help me in this??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.hb.skew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SkewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(this);
        li.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        li.addView(new MyView(this),this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 100);
    //    li.addView(new MyView(this),this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 100);

        setContentView(li);
    }
}
class MyView extends View{

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        public MyView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                setFocusable(true);
                setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);

                        RectF rf= new RectF();
                        rf.left=20;
                        rf.top=0;
                        rf.bottom=100;
                        rf.right=100;

                        canvas.skew(+0f, +0.3f);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), null, rf ,paint);
                        //canvas.drawRect(20, 30, 100, 130, paint);    
                        canvas.restore();
                        rf.left+=50;
                        rf.top=30;
                        rf.bottom=130;
                        rf.right+=100;
                        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), null, rf ,paint);

                        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), x, y ,paint);

        }

        float x,y;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


                x=event.getX();
                y=event.getY();


                invalidate();
                return true;
        }

}
```

---

```
package com.hb.skew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SkewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(this);
        li.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        li.addView(new MyView(this),this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 100);
    //    li.addView(new MyView(this),this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 100);

        setContentView(li);
    }
}
class MyView extends View{

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

            RectF rf= new RectF();
            rf.left=20;
            rf.top=0;
            rf.bottom=100;
            rf.right=100;

            canvas.skew(+0f, +0.3f);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), null, rf ,paint);
            //canvas.drawRect(20, 30, 100, 130, paint); 
            canvas.restore();
            rf.left+=50;
            rf.top=30;
            rf.bottom=130;
            rf.right+=100;
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), null, rf ,paint);

            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon), x, y ,paint);

    }

    float x,y;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();


        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: -1, links are not answers. When that link goes dead or if the site goes down, your answer becomes useless. Please provide enough context in your answer so that it can stand alone.